# How can I see callerIP on BigQuery's AuditLog?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, audit-logging

I use BigQuery's AuditLog to see access from outside my company to BigQuery with `callerIP` in "requestMetadata" field in "protoPayload" field, but value in `callerIP` has disappeared somehow since 2018/9/1 on Japan time when "methodName" in "protoPayload" field is set as "jobservice.jobcompleted".
`callerIP` is shown as usual when "methodName" is set as others like "jobservice.insert", "jobservice.query" and so on.

Has the specification on BigQuery's AuditLog been changed about showing `callerIP`?
How should I do to show `callerIP` again when "methodName" is set as "jobservice.jobcompleted"?
(though it seems seeing "jobservice.query" also works, if I just want to see access from outside my company to BigQuery with `callerIP`).

cf:[AuditLog](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/audit/auditlog/rest/Shared.Types/AuditLog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired data back by doing a self join:

```
SELECT a.protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerIp 
FROM `your-project.audit.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_20180904`  a
JOIN `your-project.audit.cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access_20180904`  b
ON 
 a.protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobInsertResponse.resource.jobName.jobId
 =b.protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobName.jobId
```

I don't have additional info on why these changes were implemented, but I can confirm that in August both rows showed the callerIp - while now only the jobInsertResponse one does.